# Is the Password stored in RAM in clear text after decrypting the MultiBit HD wallet?

Tags: wallet, security, client, multibit, encryption

After decrypting your wallet in MultiBit HD, is the clear text version of password stored in the RAM?

Comment: Well, it has to be, at least for a short time. A good implementation will ensure that cleartext passwords are cleared when they are no longer needed.

Comment: I load up wallet
. Enter decryption password. 
Wallet loads up. 1 hour passes. 
Someone looks into my memory at this time

Comment: I'd assume they just put it in a buffer. Read the key into memory, only read it directly into a static buffer, after use clear the buffer with zeroes.